# Is it possible to add new menu bar to right side of editor - VSCode Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In editor top right side, is there any way to add new menubar item and attach a command on it?

afaik i can only add entries to existing menu item using ["menus" / "editor/title"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesmenus).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"editor/title"`, which you already linked to, should be the correct location. Here's an example from the built-in Markdown extension, which [uses it to add the "Open Preview To The Side" button](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/b936b570bdf314fee71252a729b65fec2389ff52/extensions/markdown-language-features/package.json#L83-L89) in `.md` files:

```json
"contributes": {
    "menus": {
        "editor/title": [
            {
                "command": "markdown.showPreviewToSide",
                "when": "editorLangId == markdown",
                "alt": "markdown.showPreview",
                "group": "navigation"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### A little normalization

The "editor top right side" and "new menubar item" are called Editor Toolbar and Editor Action in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-guidelines#architecture) (look for #10 in this chapter), although no one is using it in the documentation.

### Solving the problem

##### Show the command button of `Editor Action`

The contribution point is [`editor/title` in `contributes.menus`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) like you said.

After adding this to your `package.json`

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "menus": {
      "editor/title": [
        {
          "command": "<YOUR_SPECIFIC_COMMAND>",
          "when": "editorLangId == <YOUR_LANG_ID>",
          "group": "navigation"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

##### Style `Editor Action` with icon

You will also need to give this same `<YOUR_SPECIFIC_COMMAND>` an icon, the commands should be defined in [contributes.commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.commands), and to use an icon from [products icon](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels#icon-listing) (rather than `.svg` in the example), you should use a syntax like this:
note that the this `<YOUR_SPECIFIC_COMMAND>` should be the same as before.

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "<YOUR_SPECIFIC_COMMAND>",
        "title": "<THIS_WILL_SHOW_IN_CMD_PALETTE_AND_ON_HOVER>",
        "category": "<THIS_WILL_SHOW_IN_CMD_PALETTE_BEFORE_COMMAND>",
        "icon": "$(<default_codicon_ID>)"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```